# SQL Server Management Studio crashes after opening or creating database diagram

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms, sql-server-2012

I have an error message that occurs every time I use SQL Server 2012 Management Studio to open or create a new database diagram, followed by an automatic restart of SSMS.

The error message is

> *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt. 
>   (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)*

Here's what I did to produce this problem:

Earlier, I had installed SQL Server 2008: via an option available when I downloaded Visual Basic Express 2010.  No errors yet. I could create and edit database diagrams without problems. Then I uninstalled VB Express 2010, and installed Visual Studio 2012, only to find out that it was a trial version, which I didn't like, so I uninstalled Visual Studio 2012. I launched SSMS 2008 and tried to open a database diagram in one of my databases. I received an error that said

> *Specified Module cannot be Found. (MS Visual Database Tools)*

I installed SQL Server 2012 with Management Studio, and then used the SSMS 2012 to try opening the database diagram. And instead of `Specified module` error, I got the error about attempting to read or write protected memory.

I am running Windows 7, SQL Server 2012 Express and I didn't uninstall SQL Sever 2008 Express (yet), Visual C# 2010 Express, Visual Basic 2010 Express.

EDIT: I *attempted* to fix this problem by applying a hotfix named SQLServer2012_RTM_CU1_kb2679368_11_0_2316_x64.  It did *not* fix the problem.  The hotfix was suggested by a user in an MSDN forum at this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/1753d7ba-f6ec-4a8e-a1c9-ded2a5b7c607

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the answer, thanks to another post  [located here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/730985/smss-crashes-when-creating-new-database-diagram#).  Basically, even though my visual studio 2012 install was the trial version, it seemed to cause the same problem as the visual studio described in the link.  Check it for a workaround.

Comment: Consider posting the content that is pertinent instead of just a link. Someone could come by 6 years later and the answer won't be any good.

Comment: Link is now broken. Can't find new URL.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same issue. Mine is SQL 2012 in windows7. I was trying connect to a sql server 2014 in Windows 2012 R2.

The problem was resolved after I upgraded my SQL 2012 client to 2014.

It is interesting that it was fine to work with SQL2014 with Windows 2012 but not windows 2012 R2.

Comment: this seems like a comment

Comment: @loctrice it is also a solution. And it is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> For the sake of completeness I added this answer with all steps
>   required to solve this issue

It is a stupid error, which can occur in nearly all sersion of SQL Server Management Studio.

Look for a machine that had SSMS installed which ist still working without any error.

Copy **all** files of the folder from the working machine to the faulting machine

> **Folder 1:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\
>
> **Folder 2:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8\

Start SSMS again and the error is gone

> verified for 2008R2, 2012, 2014

Answer (score 0):

I was used to get this message and to get the management closed ALL-THE-TIME

when I notice a pattern in the bug ( and given the message I guessed the bug was isolated when trying to deal with the diagram database objects in the memory), if I create the diagram, place a table, put the first column with pk, save, close and open the diagram again it started working...

I used to repeat this for every new table added in the diagram without saving in disk

somehow, it stopped happening maybe after some updates in the host

I hope it works for you too

Comment: Hi Edwin, Whenever I try to create a database diagram, the program gives the error message and crashes, so I can't even try what you suggest to do with creating a diagram first.